# Miktex with problem to compile makeglossaries

Tags: miktex, glossaries, texmaker, perl

I'm using texmaker and trying to create a glossary from a glossary.tex file.
but I'm getting the error:

> Sorry, but makeglossaries did not succeed for the following reason:
> MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required
> to execute 'makeglossaries'. Remedy: Make sure 'perl.exe' is installed
> on your system. The log file hopefully contains the information to get
> MiKTeX going again:
> C:\Programs\MiKTex\texmfs\data\miktex\log\makeglossaries.log For more
> information, visit: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-script-engine-not-found

I have followed the steps described in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410606/texmaker-makeglossaries-the-script-engine-could-not-be-found)

I have installed perl in my computer through ActiveState, and I checked, because when I go to cmd and type perl --version is printed the msg:

> This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 0 (v5.32.0) built for
> MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

The problem is that I can't find the folder like

> C:\perl\bin)

I only have the folder from ActiveState which doesn't has this folder inside.
So I add to the PATH the ActiveState folder (I don't know if this is the right solution)

I have restarted Texmaker, but still getting the same error.

This is my code for latex:

```
\usepackage{ae} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[
nonumberlist, %do not show page numbers
acronym,      %generate acronym listing
toc,          %show listings as entries in table of contents
section=section,automake]      %use section level for toc entries
{glossaries}



\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of symbols}
\newcommand{\field}[1]{\protect\overrightarrow{#1}}  

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{chapters/glossary.tex}

\begin{document}
\frontPage
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\frontmatter
\input{chapters/abstract.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\newpage
\input{chapters/acknowlegments.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}

\newpage
\tableofcontents 

\newpage
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]  % Glossary%
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]  % ACronyms %%
\newpage
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long]  % Symbols %% 

\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage

\mainmatter
\input{chapters/introduzione.tex}
\input{chapters/capitolo01.tex}
\input{chapters/capitolo02.tex}
\input{chapters/capitolo03.tex}
\input{chapters/capitolo05.tex}
\input{chapters/capitolo06.tex}

\bibliography{biba}
\backmatter
\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

and the glossary.tex is:

```
% Symbols

\newglossaryentry{symb:mu}{
name=$\mu$,
description={Magnetic permeability},
sort=symbolmu, type=symbolslist
}

%Some acronyms

\newacronym{em}{EM}{Electromagnetic Methods}
```

This is the log file from miktex:

```
2021-08-06 13:29:00,055+0100 INFO  makeglossaries - starting with command line: makeglossaries
2021-08-06 13:29:00,063+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - The script engine could not be found.
2021-08-06 13:29:00,063+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Info: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="makeglossaries"
2021-08-06 13:29:00,063+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2021-08-06 13:29:00,063+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Line: 83
2021-08-06 13:29:00,066+0100 ERROR makeglossaries - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.
2021-08-06 13:38:43,492+0100 INFO  makeglossaries - starting with command line: makeglossaries
2021-08-06 13:38:43,495+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - The script engine could not be found.
2021-08-06 13:38:43,495+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Info: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="makeglossaries"
2021-08-06 13:38:43,495+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2021-08-06 13:38:43,495+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Line: 83
2021-08-06 13:38:43,500+0100 ERROR makeglossaries - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.
2021-08-06 13:49:12,566+0100 INFO  makeglossaries - starting with command line: makeglossaries -d build
2021-08-06 13:49:12,569+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - The script engine could not be found.
2021-08-06 13:49:12,569+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Info: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="makeglossaries"
2021-08-06 13:49:12,569+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2021-08-06 13:49:12,569+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Line: 83
2021-08-06 13:49:12,570+0100 ERROR makeglossaries - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.
2021-08-06 14:00:51,043+0100 INFO  makeglossaries - starting with command line: makeglossaries -d build
2021-08-06 14:00:51,046+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - The script engine could not be found.
2021-08-06 14:00:51,046+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Info: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="makeglossaries"
2021-08-06 14:00:51,046+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2021-08-06 14:00:51,046+0100 FATAL makeglossaries - Line: 83
2021-08-06 14:00:51,048+0100 ERROR makeglossaries - minor issue: It has been a long time since you have checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

Comment: Can you please add some more information to your description? What I'm a bit confused with is: a) how does the call to the script look like in the shell (DOS, bash whatever)?, b) what does the document look like in Latex, which displays or includes the scripts result? Thank you

Comment: Where did you install Perl?

Comment: @MS-SPO I don't understand a). I'll update the question with my latex code

Comment: @Bernard I'm at university, so I have installed it only to my user, in my user account

Comment: Did you add it to the path?

Comment: I add the ActiveState folder because I didn't find the pearl, I assumed is that folder, is it?

Comment: what happens if you run makeglossaries --help on the command line?

Comment: I just use the `xindy` option

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it gives an error :  Sorry, but makeglossaries did not succeed for the following reason:

  MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required to execute 'makeglossaries'.

Comment: This is in the same command line where `perl --version`  give a message?

Comment: I don't know if this applies here, but in 21.7 a Perl related bug was fixed: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/871

Answer (score 0):

Referring to comment

> @MS-SPO I don't understand a). I'll update the question with my latex
> code – Jeniffer Barreto 29 mins

Valid remark. I'm not sure how the `glossaries` package deals with perl. Skimming through its huge User Manual at https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf it describes a series of command line calls on page 50. The important one wrt your question is this one, a **mandatory (?)** hint:

```
You may need to **explicitly** loadmakeglossaries into Perl:
$perl makeglossaries myDoc
```

(Just in case: the `$` sign simply indicates the prompt from the DOS command shell, bash on Linux or whatever system you are on. It can be any sign.)

Now this call from the command shell does not always work with Active Perl om Windows for some reason. A way to deal with it is to specify the whole path to perl.exe, like so:

```
$cd yourLatexDocumentsDirectory
$C:\bin\whereveritis\perl.exe  makeglossaries myDoc
```

An error proven way to do this is to:

- open the explorer at the location of perl.exe
- drag perl.exe into the DOS shell
- add makegloss...

With this in mind item a) from my comment should be clear ;-)
Success :)

**P.S.**: In best case your reported errors will be gone by now. However, if not, I suggest to distill down both your document and the glossary-source and work from there. It should be easier to identify the real trouble maker this way. I.e. make both as simple as possible BUT still retain at least one of those errors.

**P.S.**: Looks like the command shell copies in the User Manual are from the Linux world. Should change much in the world of DOS and Windows ...

Comment: sorry no. makeglossaries should work in miktex if perl is in the path.

Comment: "Being in the path" seems to be the problem with Active Perl ;-) Is there a different place to specify it besides using the operating systems PATH-variable?

Comment: My problem is the ActiveState, I can't understand it, because has no folder with perl/bin, so I don't know what to add to PATH. Is there another way to install perl ?

Comment: @MS-SPO I can't find the perl.exe file

Comment: @JenifferBarreto I have strawberry perl

Comment: @JenifferBarreto, there are several ways to find out. On Linux enter which perl into a command shell. On Windows click on the Windows Start Symbol, enter perl.exe or just perl and make your choice. Or open the explorer, set it to C: and sort by date; perhaps repeat in the program related folders. // Strawberry, as Ulrike comments, perl is worth a try. // I'm sure you are close to a solution.